# I can't find windows defender in regedit

Tags: windows-registry

I can't find Windows Defender in `regedit`.

Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender

it only shows

- Policies
- Microsoft
- Cryptography
- Peernet
- System Certificates
- Windows
- Windows NT

Next should come Windows Defender but it is not there. I am trying to fix Error code - 0x800705b4.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. It would help if you could explain how you are trying to fix Error code - 0x800705b4 and what you have done so far.

Comment: Windows defender is listed in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\
Are you trying to change policies?

Comment: Claim about registry entries is unfounded; no connection between error and registry entries is cited.

Answer (score 0):

0x800705b4 : This error code will happen in windows defender **if any third party antivirus or firewall disabled your windows defender temporarily**.

Browse registry again after disabling the third party antivirus

From [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/0x800705b4-window-defender-error-code/39cfc886-bbec-4b48-9503-5a6c59bd1694)

> Step 1
>
> If you have any third party antivirus software and firewall
>   disable them temporarily and make sure that the Windows Firewall is
>   turned on. Then check if the issue reappears.
>
> Step 2
>
> 1. Open Run, and  type in services.msc then press Enter.
> 2. In services window, locate Windows Defender service in the services list.
> 3. Verify that the Status is Started. If the Status column is blank, right click on the service and select Start.
>
> 4  If you get error trying
>   to force start the Windows Defender service, try to change the Startup
>   Type to Automatic, and then restart the computer.